# How to make the "Locals and Expressions" debugging window operational with gcc 4.8?

Tags: gcc, qt-creator

I am using gcc 4.7 and gcc 4.8 together with QtCreator 2.7.1.

The problem is that when I use **gcc 4.8**, I am unable to see the values of my variables in the  **"Locals and Expressions"** window in debug mode:

[image]

While **gcc 4.7** works fine:

[image]

I have tried to repair this by playing with the QtCreator options, but to no avail.

I am not sure, if this has actually something to do with the compiler version, but the problem goes away once I rebuild with the older version.

Comment: Try updating your GDB to at least 7.5 (current is 7.6).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason probably is that gcc 4.8 is using by default newer format for storing debugging information (http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html). If you are using gdb version less than 7.5 (see `gdb --version`) you need to provide `-gdwarf-3` argument for compiling with debug info using gcc 4.8.

Comment: ``-gdwarf-3`` worked for me with gcc 5.1 and gdb 7.9.1

Answer (score 8):

The same symptom can result from having a debugger that is **too new**, instead of **too old**!

In this case it's not about the GDB version, it's about the version of Python which was embedded into it when it was built.  Ubuntu 13.10 ships with a GDB that's built with embedded Python3 instead of Python2.  Qt Creator (at the time of this writing) is not compatible with that.

You can check to see if you've got a Python2 GDB by running it from a terminal and typing:

```
(gdb) python print sys.version
```

If you get an invalid syntax error, you've probably got Python3.  That requires parentheses around what to print, so try:

```
(gdb) python print(sys.version)
```

When that comes back with a `3.x.x` answer, Qt Creator's Python debugging scripts won't work (yet).  So you'll need to get a GDB with Python2.

Here's my blog entry about it: [QtCreator Debugger Not Showing Locals in Ubuntu 13.10](http://hostilefork.com/2013/10/20/qtcreator-debugger-no-locals-ubuntu/).

Comment: Oh my god, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: @HostileFork: I read from your blog that Qt Creator 3 has this issue fixed; however I've Qt Creator 3.0.1 and with MinGW's GDB 7.6 (prints 2.7.5 as Python's version) I still see that locals are not populated :(

Comment: @legends2k I've been busy with other things and have not done the 3.0 install, so I cannot verify what the comments reported myself.  Does following the blog procedure fix the problem?  If not, it could be something else.  :-/  MinGW is, in my limited experience, always a little bit "fringe" and one has to be crafty with it.

Comment: Agree with you on the "fringe" part; yet to try building GDB myself with python support (as your blog says), using `-gdwarf-3` for the time being which works.

Comment: Everyone is going to qt5 right now but not all at the same time, and in paralell, everyone is going from Python 2 to 3 as well... this is a classic example of why it's so important to maintain backward compatibility when releasing newer versions of your software. I hope all the developers here take note of how easily things are getting broken when ABIs are changed and everything becomes broken which is funny because people are ALWAYS talking about not doing it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it was what HostileFork described: ubuntu 13.10 + Qt Creator 2.8

This [bug](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-10161) has been fixed in Qt Creator 3, not yet released.

To solve this without recompiling GDB, just use the release candidate of Qt Creator 3.

There are builds available **[on Qt project website](http://download.qt-project.org/development_releases/qtcreator/3.0/3.0.0-rc1/)** or a PPA (ppa:p12/qtcreator) with last git version but build is broken as of today.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enabled Views->Locals
[image]