# qtcreator can not show local variables and expression

Tags: qt, gdb, qt-creator

I don't know why my qtcreator can not display "local variables and expression" window.
OS: ubuntu 12.04,
gcc: gcc 4.8,
g++: g++ 4.8,
gdb: gdb 7.5.1,

but when I change gcc and g++ down to 4.7, it is ok.
Why?

Comment: Do you see this error `>&"Undefined command: \"bb\".  Try \"help\".\n"` in Debugger Log?

Comment: This question has already been asked and, happily, answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611678/how-to-make-the-locals-and-expressions-debugging-window-operational-with-gcc-4)

Answer (score 0):

It seems, **gdb 7.5.1** is not fully compatible **gcc 4.8** and **g++ 4.8**. All in all, showing variables and etc. is just about **debugger** not the QtCreator itself.

Comment: What version of gdb should be used then?

Comment: I don't know the version, you need to search and find out.. Or maybe someone who knows should answer..