# Compilation GDB give error

Tags: gdb

Related to problem [16611678](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611678/how-to-make-the-locals-and-expressions-debugging-window-operational-with-gcc-4) I need a new version of gdb in my centos 6.5 64.
I try to compile GDB (7.7, 7.6.2 and 7.5), without success, the error is related to `get_tty_state()` in `ser-unix.c`:

```
ser-unix.c:118:1: error: conflicting types for ‘get_tty_state’
```

My gcc version is 4.8.2

Before the function declaration there is preprocessor directives for defining `hardwire_ttystate` if `HAVE_TERMIOS` is defined and I think the problem come from here (if needed I can post the piece of code), as `HAVE_TERMIOS` is undefined.

Any help would be appreciated!

Nathanaël

Comment: centos 6.5 comes with gcc 4.4.7, and I've successfully built gdb 7.7 on centos 6.5. Do you still have gcc 4.4.7 available on that system?

Comment: Yes, I try with gcc 4.4.7 and this give me the same error

Comment: Finally build gdb in a fresh centos and copy the installation files in my usual centos.