# How to return debug window in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

When I run C++ program under qt creator in debug mode, Qt creator shows me debug window with "local and expressions", "breakpoints" and so on.

Sometimes I close these windows to watch the code by pressing Esc. How to return this views back? I really need to loot at stack trace right now, but I can't find a button to show me the stack.

I [looked at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611678/how-to-make-the-locals-and-expressions-debugging-window-operational-with-gcc-4) but it didn't help. My debugging window working well, but when I close it, I cannot open it again. The only way - restart whole program, than debugging view appear again and I can operate with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make the "Locals and Expressions" debugging window operational with gcc 4.8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16611678/how-to-make-the-locals-and-expressions-debugging-window-operational-with-gcc-4)

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debug-mode.html

Comment: @FirstStep, it is totally different question.

Comment: Have you tried selecting *Window > Views > Reset to Default Layout*?

Comment: @N.Shead, Window > Views become inactive when I close debug view. http://imgur.com/piYf4wv

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to go back to the "Debug" mode by clicking on the debug (bug) icon on the left hand side.

You can do so by pressing CTRL + 4.

Comment: You are the best! :-)

Answer (score 4):

"Debug" mode and CTRL + 4 didn't help me, so here is another solution:

Click "Views" which should be on the dark grey bar in the lower right area of your user interface, in small print. There you can check or uncheck any of the Debug windows you want to see.

I find it easier to just click "Reset to Default Layout" under this menu because I'm not hard to please and it brings all the debug windows I want to see back instantly.